# Is it posible to ignore rest of some text in a row?

Tags: php, sql

I try to make a delete function but in my db it has a lot of text in the row, is it posible to ignore rest of the text and only remove from the id.

In the db the row has this text chest:u101veh_elegy and i want to ignore the rest "elegy" so it will delete the rows no matter what it says after the veh_

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE dkey='chest:u".$_POST['id']."veh_'";
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminently

Comment: also, this is why primary auto_incremented keys are important in a table.

Comment: Creating different columns for the data you want to be able to access/reference on their own might also be an idea. It's rarely a good idea to store multiple values in one column. At least not if you want to be able to get only parts of the data.

Comment: Which extension do you use? MySQLi or PDO?

Comment: i use MySQLi ..

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get, why you are doing it, but here is an example using `PDO`:

```php
$dkeyLike = "chest:u{$_POST['id']}veh_%";
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE dkey LIKE ?";

$db->prepare($sql)->execute([$dkeyLike]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with MySQLi as follows:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$string = 'chest:u'.$_POST['id'].'veh_%';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE dkey LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $string);
$stmt->execute();
```

Use `LIKE` and wildcard `%` to specify partial string. It will match `chest:u101veh_elegy` if id is 101.

Remember please, to never put PHP variables directly into SQL queries as this is very dangerous. Always use parameterized prepared statements! Consider switching to PDO also, which might prove to be beneficial for you, as demonstrated by the other answer which is much simpler.